# How to download a flash video from a website?

Tags: flash, download

I want to download some free training videos from a website, which belongs to STMicrocontrollers. I know how to inspect objects, but I didn't find any link to download. This is the URL:
https://st-onlinetraining.s3.amazonaws.com/STM32L4_Introduction_Welcome_session/index.html
Can you give me a solution to download this file? (of course, there are more file and I don't search for an answer for a short introduction movie)
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That shown [site link](https://st-onlinetraining.s3.amazonaws.com/STM32L4_Introduction_Welcome_session/index.html) does not use Flash to show video. All it does is show a slideshow of HTML pages with an audio tag playing MP3 sound for that slide.

Example for slide 1:

- In [slide1.js](https://st-onlinetraining.s3.amazonaws.com/STM32L4_Introduction_Welcome_session/data/slide1.js) you can see the HTML code starts from the first `<div id=` up to last/ending `</div>`.
- This is the [MP3 sound](https://st-onlinetraining.s3.amazonaws.com/STM32L4_Introduction_Welcome_session/data/sound1.mp3) for slide 1.

You will have to a create an HTML page, screenshot that as a `.jpg` or .`png`, then use a tool like FFmpeg to combine the slide's image and sound into a video.